# Issue on Matching the string and replacing the hex in python

Tags: python, regex, datetime

```
st = """
    What kind of speCialist would we see for this?He also seems to have reactions to the red dye cochineal/carmine cialist,I like Cialist much
 """
```

here I need to replace only the Cialist string(exact match) also it may has comma at the end

The word "spe*cialist*" should not be thrown

i tried with this regex.

```
 bold_string = "<b>"+"Cialist"+"</b>"
 insensitive_string = re.compile(re.escape("cialist"), re.IGNORECASE)
 comment = insensitive_string.sub(bold_string,st)
```

but it throws the string **specialist** also.

Could you suggest me to fix this?

One more issue with replacing the hexadecimal character in python.

```
 date_str = "28-06-2010\xc3\x82\xc2\xa008:48 PM"
 date_str = date_str.replace("\n","").replace("\t","").replace("\r","").replace("\xc3\x82\xc2\xa"," ")
 date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str,"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %p")
 Error: time data '08-09-2005\xc3\x82\xc2\xa010:18 PM' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %p'
```

Here I am not able to replace the hex characters with space for matching with datetime pattern .

Could you please help out of this issue?

Comment: In `"\xc3\x82\xc2\xa"`, `\xa` isn't a valid escape sequence. Did you mean `\xa0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second Q:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\\[a-zA-z0-9]{2}', lambda L: str(int(L.group()[2:], 16)), text)
'28-06-20101238212210008:48 PM'
```

That either re-organise that for your strptime, or have strptime interpret that.

Comment: Sorry this should be written as `re.sub(r'\\[a-f0-9]{2}', lambda L: str(int(L.group()[2:], 16)), text, flags=re.I)`

Answer (score 0):

Use \b to match a word boundary. Then it becomes simples :)

```
import re

st = """
    What kind of speCialist would we see for this?He also seems to have reactions to the red dye cochineal/carmine cialist,I like Cialist much
 """

print re.sub(r'\bCialist\b', "<b>Cialist</b>", st)
```

For the second question you're missing a 0 at the end of your last replace string. Just add 0 and it works :)

```
date_str = "28-06-2010\xc3\x82\xc2\xa008:48 PM"
print date_str
date_str = date_str.replace("\n","").replace("\t","").replace("\r","").replace("\xc3\x82\xc2\xa0"," ")
print repr(date_str)
```

Comment: insensitive_string = re.compile(re.escape(r'\b'+drug_name+'\b'), re.IGNORECASE)  Adding boundary with these params? not working

Answer (score 0):

Two questions in one?

replace your regex with a word boundary so it's `re.sub(r'\bcialist\b', '', your_string, re.I)`

Comment: sorry, Here I am facing problem  s = "nava cialist specialist..",name = "cialist",insensitive_string = re.compile(re.escape(name), re.IGNORECASE),bold_string = "<b>nava</b>", comment = insensitive_string.sub(r"'\b'+bold_string+'\b'",s)  Boundary property is not working

Comment: Use a negative look behind assertion: (?<!spe)cialist

Comment: Just I want the generic soln like instead of the specialist some other  can have the substring as 'cialist'